# benefits of using EncodePointer/DecodePointer

Tags: c++, winapi

What is the benefits of using **EncodePointer** / **DecodePointer** in Windows?

`MSDN` say:
    Encoding globally available pointers helps protect them from being exploited.
    The **EncodePointer** function obfuscates the pointer value with a secret so that it cannot be predicted by an external agent. The secret used **EncodePointer** is different for each process.

Now question is: If the attacker is outside of my program, then its address space is different from my address space, so an address in my app is not usable for it.
and if it can execute a code in my address space it can call **DecodePointer** and use that address to call encoded pointer.

So what is the usage of this functions and how they help me with increased security?

Comment: What if the attacker is *not* outside your program? Like, say... every single attacker in history?

Comment: @KerrekSB If it is in my program?! Then it can simply call **DecodePointer** on my function pointer and then normally call it. What is the benefit of encoding something while decoding as simple as calling a function without any key or something like that? and what make attacker unable of calling **DecodePointer**?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are missing the intention, EncodePointer() protects against malicious **data**.  Before malicious code can become harmful it needs to start running first.  Basic ways to get that done is by overwriting the return address of a function call or by overwriting a function pointer.  The program itself now activates the code by respectively returning from the function or calling through the function pointer.

EncodePointer protects a function pointer. There isn't any way for the attacker to guess how to encode the data they write so that after the program's DecodePointer() call it still points to the malicious code.

Data cannot call EncodePointer.

Answer (score 0):

Attackers with elevated privileges can create a thread in your process. Kernel code can also map parts of the virtual address of your process to another user process and/or the system process.

Using EncodePointer will only make things a little harder for the attacker but not guaranty anything.