# Does a 32 bit application running on 64 bit Windows still need to be compiled with SAFESEH?

Tags: c++, windows, 64-bit

Does a 32 bit application running under WOW64 on a 64 bit version of windows still benefit from being compiled with the SAFESEH flag?

I understand this is irrelevant for 64 bit applications however I was unsure for 32 bit applications in the above context and have not been able to find an answer whilst googling.

Comment: It is not necessary and not very effective since you can't demand this for libraries you didn't create.  Microsoft added another counter-measure: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20260523/benefits-of-using-encodepointer-decodepointer

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: Yes.

> /SAFESEH is only valid when linking for x86 targets. [/SAFESEH is not supported for platforms that already have the exception handlers noted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/safeseh-image-has-safe-exception-handlers?view=vs-2019). For example, on x64 and ARM, all exception handlers are noted in the PDATA

Even when running under WOW64 a 32-bit x86 app will still use the FS register to store the SEH chain and all the normal security issues apply. /SAFESEH will add a table of handlers to the PE file that is used in the exact same way as on a 32-bit version of Windows. SAFESEH is a compiler+OS feature (WinXP.SP2?) and the Windows part of it lives in NTDLL, not the kernel. If the OS component is missing (older Windows version) it would just act like normal SEH.

You can also think about it another way: You don't know ahead of time if the user is going to run you application on a 32 or 64 bit version of Windows.